# Change maximum number of notification icons?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, cyanogenmod, notification-icons

My phone shows only three app notification icons in the status bar at most, but there is space for six (most of the time).

**How can I increase/change the maximum number of notifications shown at once?**

I don’t care if they end up overlapping with system indicators on the right.

I run CyanogenMod 7.1 (rooted, s-off, adb available, compiler as well...) and editing the source is acceptable.

Comment: Not sure if this is possible without actually editing the Android source (CM source, etc.).

Comment: That question is a bit out of scope here, I would ask on StackOverflow.com. I've never altered the Android source, so unfortunately I can't point you in the right direction.

Comment: You would need to edit SystemUI.

Answer (score -1):

Number of icon to show on status bar depends on programmer how he wrote that **status bar application code** . We really can't do much here.
You should be contacting customer support of developers of CyanogenMod 7.1
they might consider your request and change it to your needs.

Comment: Wrong. It does not solely depend on the application. – I would vote you down, if I could.

Comment: @RobertSiemer : Hey, Can I know other factors on which it depends other than application?

Comment: The operating system itself. – On my phone, right now, two unrelated applications and their icon (WifiKeyboard and SL4A) get folded into one icon with a red circle and a “2” in it. But I was thinking last night about what I said: I would not vote you down anymore, because I’m not entirely sure if those apps indicate some “allow folding my icon”. – In the end it has to be the Android framework which does start doing so at some point. – I want to control whether it does, and at which point.

Comment: @RobertSiemer : This Statusbar code is in framework. So when I said status bar app, I meant framework and developers of CyanogenMod 7.1 can change it.